# Refresh HTML Table Using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm confused on how to refresh an HTML table using AJAX.

I'm not the developer of the site, so I dont have the server side information. I cant find anyway to reload the table on this page:  http://www.roblox.com/Poison-Horns-item?id=62152671

I understand that you need to request a document for AJAX to work, but I cant find the document on the page. Im just the user >.> - which makes me assume ajax is mostly for the people who develop the sites.

Comment: The easiest way would be to just set up a refresh on a timer, or do you need to keep the page from refreshing?

Comment: contact your system administrator...

Comment: What are you trying to do, specifically? What do you mean by reload the table? You want to "refresh" only that part of the page?

Comment: @the, I have a working version that reloads the page, but this would be faster.

Comment: @sach, yes. the whole table. Specifically just the 1st row listed.

Comment: You could setup some AJAX to do it, since it's not cross-origin restricted. The code itself would have to strip out the parts you don't need and just replace the section you want or just replace the whole html.

Comment: The, Ive got no idea how to use AJAX, hence why I made this

Comment: @TheZ how do we know it's not cross-origin restricted?

Comment: Because, he just said he wants to reload the page he's on, if you write an extension for Chrome (for example) that works on that page then it will not be origin-restricted since it runs in situ.

Comment: But still, when you do an AJAX request, what will you be requesting? You'd get the whole page and then filter out your results. How is that easier than just refreshing the page? My understanding is that he wants to stay on the page with the contents of the table updating. It's more work for what?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to reload just part of the page unless you have some way of getting that part. From a developer perspective, they can request just the table data from the server and show it on the screen, updating automatically.

You, being just the user, get the entire page when you load it. So no, you won't be able to just get the table data without getting the rest of the page. Even if you want just the table part, you have to request the entire page.

Your best bet is to have a script that reloads the entire page. This can be done with a web page and iFrame with the site loaded in the iFrame and a script that just reloads the frame every so often.

```
<iframe id="frame" src="http://mysite.com"></iframe>​

setInterval(reload,1000)

function reload() {
    document.getElementById("frame").src=document.getElementById("frame").src;
}
```

The above code will reload the page every `1000ms`.

Regarding AJAX being quicker than reloading the page:

This is true, if you only request the data using AJAX and then update the page on the client side. In this case, there is minimal data transfer between client and server so everything is faster. In your case, you'd still have to request the entire page even if you did it with AJAX. Websites with AJAX have an API that allows the client to request specific information from the server to make things faster. You don't have that here.

From what I understand, you just want something that checks the price of an item and alert you if it's below a threshold. If this is the case, I would use a Chrome Extension that allows you to inject JS into webpages. Something like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gidddlfmjhjiibffpalikbecknoflfab).

The following jQuery selector gets you the price of the first item. You can adjust the threshold price and interval (`300000ms = 5 minutes`).

```
var price = $("#UserSalesTab > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3) > b").html().match(/[0-9]+/)[0]
if (price < 100) alert("BUY");
setInterval(reload, 300000)
```

Comment: Ive got that down using 'iframe.onload = loaded' loaded being a function when the iframe loads. I get all that, its just AJAX would work quicker :/

Comment: Is your page on the same domain? If not AJAX won't work because you get [cross-origin restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: sach, i made a javascript that checks prices in the table and if low enough, it will buy. Ive been told AJAX is quicker than refreshing the whole page.

Comment: @Alex I've updated my answer with an explanation on AJAX being quicker. From what I understand, you just want something that checks the price of an item and alert you if it's below a threshold, is this correct?

Comment: @sachleen You can do cross domain ajax requests if you use JSONP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: @sachleen, it works, but does it get the latest price everytime it runs?

Comment: It'll get the price that you would see if you were to reload the page manually.

Comment: @sachleen it doesnt seem to be working. this is what ive got 'function reload(){
var price = $("#UserSalesTab > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3) > b").html().match(/\d+/)[0];
if (Number(price) < 800){
alert(price);
}
}
setInterval(reload, 2000);'

Comment: Right, because that's just getting the same price from the same page. `reload` needs to reload the page and then `document.ready` you get the price.